# Realizar Agrupación en linq en C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

En la siguiente consulta:

```
 public IEnumerable<Station> Get(int idapp)
    {
        Station item = null;
        List<Station> lst = new List<Station>();
        string idsp = "";
        string cnns = "";

        if (idapp == 1)
        {
            cnns = connectionStringPremier;
            idsp = "dbo.usp_Get_StationsG500";
        }
        else
        {
            cnns = connectionStringTicketCar;
            idsp = "dbo.usp_Get_StationsG500Fleet";
        }

        using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(cnns))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            lst = cnn.Query<Station>(idsp, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: cnn.ConnectionTimeout).ToList();

            cnn.Close();
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

Deseo agrupar por dos propiedades del objeto  que compone la lista, ejemplo en SQL:

```
GROUP BY  b.id_merchant,  b.description;
```

Posterior a esto me gustaría retornarlo en la Lista.

Las propiedades del objeto son:

```
public int nIdMerchant { get; set; }
public string sDescription { get; set; }
public int nIdState { get; set; }
```

La idea es que tarde lo menos posible en recuperar de la Base de Datos, puesto que si le incluyo el `Group` desde la Base de Datos se tarda demasiado la consulta.

Comment: Me suena raro que definir un `group by` en la consulta de la db se demore, si lo hace es porque no analizaron el `plan de ejecucion` (esto se realiza con el Management Studio), quizas agregar un indice por algun campo resuelve el problema y no necesitas agrupar con linq desde quien obtiene los datos

Comment: ademas hay algo raro, vas agrupar por un campo Id ? como es que se duplican los registros para que necesites agrupar por id y descripcion, entiendo que puede tener mas de un estado ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini En efecto el campo ID, no es autoincrementable, pertenece a un catalogo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El linq podria ser

```
var query = from item in lst 
             group item by item.nIdMerchant into g
             select new {
                  IdMerchant = g.Key,
                  Description = g.First(x=>x.sDescription),
                  States = g.Select(x=> x.nIdState).ToList()
             };
```

En este caso los estados seran una `List<int>`, porque entiendo puede aber mas de uno para el `IdMerchant`